# Plotting error with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, point

I have data with three variables and I am now trying to plot two of them using ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
x=1:50
y=x^2
z=rep(c("p","sp","n","sn","nt"),each=10)
mydata=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

According to the data, the plot should be a curve. However, when I run the code, I get the following figure which makes no sense. Is there any mistake in the code? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a matrix using `cbind` it coerces to the most common type, in this case, `character`. When you call `as.data.frame.matrix` It will by default create `factors`, giving you this unusual ordering based on the increasing levels of the `factor`. The correct function to use is `data.frame` with several arguments of the columns of your data.

```
library(ggplot2)
x=1:50
y=x^2
z=rep(c("p","sp","n","sn","nt"),each=10)
mydata= data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
```

Have a look at `str(data.frame(x,y,z))` instead of `str(as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))` and note the coercion to factor from integer and numeric modes.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, `as.data.frame` with `cbind`will convert the data into factor. Thank you for your help.